# How to fix load duplicate data in Android

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-json, gson

I want load data from server and show into `RecyclerView`, for connection library i use `Retrofit`. and in my application i **check internet connection**! if connected load data else show another layout.
**My codes:**

```
boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();
...

private void loadDataCheckNet() {
    loadData(isConnected);
}

private void loadData(boolean isConnect) {

    if (isConnect) {
        Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);
        Call<R_SearchModelResponse> call = apiInterface.getSearchResponse(searchText);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<R_SearchModelResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<R_SearchModelResponse> call, Response<R_SearchModelResponse> response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    models.addAll(response.body().getPosts());
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if (mAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                        search_recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                        searchLoadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        empty_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        searchLoadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else {
                    searchLoadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    TastyToast.makeText(context, "Error", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                }

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                searchCheckNet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<R_SearchModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("CatResponseError", "Error : " + t);
            }
        });
    } else {
        searchCheckNet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.clear();
            search_recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
        searchCheckNetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                loadDataCheckNet();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When running application and **isConnected** to internet application is ok, load data very good! but when disconnect internet and connect again, load data from server and again duplicate is! 
**For example :** if you have 3 post, post#1,post#2,post#3 when connected to internet load again this three posts! post#1,post#2,post#3,post#1,post#2,post#3 .

How can i fix this problem? Thanks all <3

Answer (score 1):

You just add this **models.clear();** into your public void `onResponse` method.

```
@Override
                public void onResponse(Call<R_SearchModelResponse> call, Response<R_SearchModelResponse> response) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        models.clear();
                        models.addAll(response.body().getPosts());
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if (mAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                            search_recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                            searchLoadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            empty_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            searchLoadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
```

Comment: Thnx @Mohammad, what is diffrance adapter.clear(); with model.clear(); ?

Comment: adapter is a component which contains viewgroup(AdapterView) and models (I read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)), clearing the model will remove the data from the list. here model refers to data in list @Rj.Ok

Answer (score 0):

You're just adding items to your `models` container, which I assume is some sort of list, you yes, you will have duplicates. You should `clear` your list before adding new items to it.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Define a **Method**

```
public void clearData() {
    //for remving list data
    int size = this.models.size();
    if (size > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            this.models.remove(i);
        }

        this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    }
}
```

call the method before like this

```
clearData();
models.addAll(response.body().getPosts());
```

Comment: Thnx Emdad, but what is myList?

Comment: @Emdad, best way is first remove model's or adapter's data and then fill model's data! for this job you use this code : `adapter.clear();` or `model.clear();`

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the data is duplicated because you added new data into the list without clearing old data.

One simple fix is, add this line:

```
models.clear();
```

before this line:

```
models.addAll(response.body().getPosts());
```

By the way, you should set the RecycleView adapter right after you initialized the adapter in onCreate(), there is no point in setting the same adapter to the RecycleView over and over again every time the data is Updated.